# Parameters not being replaced in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am unable to figure what is the problem here.

> I have created the below query using doctrine Query Builder

```
$repo = $this->em->getRepository(self::STORE_TIMING);
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('store_timings');
$qb->select('st')
   ->where('st.id = :identifier')
   ->setParameter('identifier', 100);
```

When i print the DQL :

```
print_r($qb->getDQL());die();
```

The query that is output is :

```
SELECT st FROM Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings store_timings WHERE st.id = :identifier
```

To my surprise the :identifier is not being replaced.

Request for some guidelines here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `getDQL` It doesn't return the query with parameter.

I advise you to use the `_profiler` to view the complete query with parameter